# Will i be removed from islam?

Tags: salat, muslim-practices

Will a person be removed from islam if he thinks he is removed from islam, but actually he is not removed from islam? (For example, if he misses his prayer partially purposefully or commits a sin)

Comment: Sorry nobody will be removed from Islam, but leaving Islam is a personal decision not something somebody else can decide, but you must accept and live with the consequences.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question very well, i had heard from someone long back that if you miss a prayer on purpose, u will be out of Islam. I had missed a prayer recently (partially purposefully) and then i got worried but then i checked the internet to see if it is true, and i got the answer as “no”. So if i think that i was out of islam but I wasn’t, will i be out of islam?

Comment: There is no concept of `out of Islam`. Even if you don't do anything, you are still following Islam. These thoughts come from Shaitan wanting you to fall in his traps. If you miss a prayer, dont stress about it.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving Islam is directly up to you. That you stop all Islamic customs and want to be no longer a Muslim. But not praying does not cause you to leave Islam. You were like a student who did not go to school for a few days. And absenteeism for a while will not be enough to expel you from the school of Islam. You are still a Muslim and you can ask God for forgiveness.
Apostasy is accomplished both verbally and With words:
Apostasy with words is when someone says something that indicates that he has left the religion of Islam. For example, say: There is no God or Muhammad (PBUH) is not a prophet or Islam is not the religion of truth. The necessary denial of religion is also of this kind. The essential meaning of religion is that its existence in Islam is so clear that it does not need to be argued and that all Muslims accept it; Such as the obligation of prayer, fasting and Hajj.

https://fa.wikishia.net/view/%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AA%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AF#%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B7_%D9%88_%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%87%E2%80%8C%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C_%D8%A7%D8%AB%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%AA_%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AA%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AF